# ActionBarDrawerToggle drawer wont slide out on button press

Tags: android, android-studio

I've tried most of the solutions I've found on stackoverflow and other random forms but to no avail. Just was a toolbar with a drawer for navigation but when i press the button on the toolbar the drawer wont slide out. But i can drag from the left to open the drawer. I don't know what im missing but i feel like its a simple fix but i just simply can't find it.
Thanks for looking!

activity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_browse_all);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarID);
    toolbar.setTitle("");
    toolbar.setSubtitle("");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    ActionBar actionBar = this.getSupportActionBar();
    if(actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);

    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onPostCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState, @Nullable PersistableBundle persistentState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(@NonNull Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    toggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
        return true;

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

activity.xml

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbar.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BrowseAllActivity" >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" >

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logolongfullcolor" />

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

---Update---

If i do this the button works.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start" >

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logolongfullcolor" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


<include layout="@layout/drawer" />

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

But this does not

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start" >

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".BrowseAllActivity" >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbarID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/gray"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logolongfullcolor" />
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<include layout="@layout/drawer" />

 </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: I think that you should totally remove the `RelativeLayout` and replace it directly with the content of your `toolbar.xml`, as it stands is totally redundant.

Comment: hmmm. so i removed relativelayout. and put just AppBarLayout and the contents and now the button works. however it destroyed my layout. but its progress

Comment: What you mean "Destroyed your layout"? I meant the whole content of your `toolbar.xml`, including the `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: The `AppBarLayout` will work as expected being a direct child of a `CoordinatorLayout`, just remove the `xmlns` attributes and move the context to the `DrawerLayout` tab.

Comment: right if i put everything including the CoordinatorLayout it doesnt work but if i remove the CoordinatorLayout the button opens the drawer. But as a results i cant see anything else in my layout.

Comment: updated my question to show you what i tried

Comment: What else are you going to add to your layout?, The thing is that if you need `scrolling behaviours` your need to use the `CoordinatorLayout` with the `AppBarLayout` as a direct child along with a scrolling `View`. If you don't need the fancyness from the `CoordinatorLayout`, the `RelativeLayout` with the `Toolbar` alone will sufice. When you put the `CoordinatorLayout`, it fails because there is no scrolling `View` that tells the `AppBarLayout` how to behave.

Comment: Removing both CoordinatorLayout and AppBarLayout and just having the toolbar in the relative layout did not fix the issue either unfortunately. My view will consist of the toolbar a ViewPager and a banner ad.

Comment: ok i got it to work! RelativeLayout -> AppBarLayout -> ToolBar. If you want to post an answer ill gladly accept it thank you for the help!

Comment: FWIW, you're overriding the wrong `onPostCreate` - you've overriden the `PersistableBundle` version, which is always the wrong one. You want the `Bundle` one.